# Uses and restrictions of Sitecore Partner License

Tags: licensing

Our organization has Sitecore Partner License.

Keen to know, how many employees can use that license to have their local Sitecore instance for Research and Development purpose?

Or are there any restrictions to use Sitecore Partner License?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no employee count restrictions, usually, for Sitecore Partner licenses. There are several usage restrictions, however. These do change over time, so it is always best to ask these sorts of questions to your partner alliance manager to get the latest information.

As a partner, you can also access the Sitecore Partner Network (SPN) by logging in at http://spn.sitecore.net. Here you can get access to more information about the Partner License on the Partner License page: http://spn.sitecore.net/Partner%20Resources/Partner%20License.aspx

From there, you can download the latest PDF on partner license usage.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2022, the Partner License page can be found here:
https://partners.sitecore.com/s/partner-license

As Jason mentions, the restrictions can change over time, but the current usages are called out:

**License expiry:**
Each Solution Partner is entitled to a single Sitecore Partner license which expires annually on **August 30th**. Partners may download a new Partner license anytime after August 1st.

**Can be used for:**

- Internal research and development
- Demonstrations of the Sitecore Products

  - Requires written authorization from Sitecore
- Development/maintenance of Sitecore Solutions for Sitecore Customers

  - Requires that the Customer's license has been purchased and issued before development work begins
- Management of your Partner Organizations web properties for up to one (1) public-facing website

  - Up to one (1) top level domain

**Cannot be used for:**

- Customer Use: No access or use of your partner license by a customer is allowed
- Development and maintenance of Sitecore Solutions for Customers: Unless a license has been purchased and issued before development work begins